# Extracting data from nested JSON with python 3

Tags: json, python-3.x, nested-loops

Looking for a way to extract data from nested json.
The data was extracted from windows scheduler as xml and converted to json. 
It represents OS scheduled tasks, there are about 100 tasks and my goal is to extract the information from json to an external DB.
This is what my json file looks like :

```
{
    "Tasks": {
        "Task": [
            {
                "RegistrationInfo": {
                    "Author": "Adobe Systems Incorporated",
                    "Description": "This task keeps your Adobe Reader and Acrobat applications up to date with the latest enhancements and security fixes",
                    "URI": "\\Adobe Acrobat Update Task"
                },
                "Principals": {
                    "Principal": {
                        "GroupId": "S-1-5-4",
                        "_id": "Author"
                    }
                },
                "Settings": {
                    "DisallowStartIfOnBatteries": "true",
                    "StopIfGoingOnBatteries": "true",
                    "MultipleInstancesPolicy": "IgnoreNew",
                    "StartWhenAvailable": "true",
                    "IdleSettings": {
                        "Duration": "PT10M",
                        "WaitTimeout": "PT1H",
                        "StopOnIdleEnd": "true",
                        "RestartOnIdle": "false"
                    }
                },
                "Triggers": {
                    "LogonTrigger": {
                        "StartBoundary": "2013-08-01T12:05:00",
                        "EndBoundary": "2027-05-02T08:00:00",
                        "Delay": "PT12M",
                        "Repetition": {
                            "Interval": "PT3H30M"
                        },
                        "_id": "TriggerUserLoggon"
                    },
                    "CalendarTrigger": {
                        "StartBoundary": "2013-01-01T09:00:00",
                        "EndBoundary": "2027-05-02T12:05:00",
                        "ScheduleByDay": {
                            "DaysInterval": "1"
                        },
                        "_id": "TriggerDaily"
                    }
                },
                "Actions": {
                    "Exec": {
                        "Command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Adobe\\ARM\\1.0\\AdobeARM.exe"
                    },
                    "_Context": "Author"
                },
                "_xmlns": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task",
                "_version": "1.2"
            },
            {
                "RegistrationInfo": {
                    "Author": "Adobe",
                    "Description": "This task keeps your Adobe Flash NPAPI Player installation up to date with the latest enhancements and security fixes. If this task is disabled or removed, Adobe Flash Player will be unable to automatically secure your machine with the latest security fixes.",
                    "URI": "\\Adobe Flash Player NPAPI Notifier"
                },
                "Principals": {
                    "Principal": {
                        "UserId": "S-1-5-21-2755204513-1269241785-1912306605-1001",
                        "LogonType": "InteractiveToken",
                        "_id": "Author"
                    }
                },
                "Settings": {
                    "DisallowStartIfOnBatteries": "false",
                    "StopIfGoingOnBatteries": "true",
                    "MultipleInstancesPolicy": "IgnoreNew",
                    "StartWhenAvailable": "true",
                    "RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable": "true",
                    "IdleSettings": {
                        "Duration": "PT10M",
                        "WaitTimeout": "PT1H",
                        "StopOnIdleEnd": "true",
                        "RestartOnIdle": "false"
                    }
                },
                "Triggers": {
                    "CalendarTrigger": {
                        "StartBoundary": "1999-12-31T16:14:00-08:00",
                        "Repetition": {
                            "Interval": "PT1H",
                            "Duration": "P1D"
                        },
                        "ScheduleByDay": {
                            "DaysInterval": "7"
                        },
                        "_id": "NotificationTrigger"
                    }
                },
                "Actions": {
                    "Exec": {
                        "Command": "C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\Macromed\\Flash\\FlashUtil32_32_0_0_330_Plugin.exe",
                        "Arguments": "-check plugin"
                    },
                    "_Context": "Author"
                },
                "_xmlns": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task",
                "_version": "1.2"
            }
```

The code below works for just one task, but i need to get the data from every task , i guess i need to find a way to insert the number of tasks to the value of index and loop them one by one ,but nothing i try works.

```
import json
index=1

with open('name.json', 'r') as f:
    array = json.load(f)

ts=(array['Tasks'])
print('Author is',ts['Task'][index]['RegistrationInfo']['Author'])
print('Description is' ,ts['Task'][index]['RegistrationInfo']['Description'])
print('URI is',ts['Task'][index]['RegistrationInfo']['URI'])
print('user ID is', ts['Task'][index]['Principals']['Principal']['UserId'])
print('Logon Type  is', ts['Task'][index]['Principals']['Principal']['LogonType'])
print(' ID is', ts['Task'][index]['Principals']['Principal']['_id'])
print(' DisallowStartIfOnBatteries is ', ts['Task'][index]['Settings']['DisallowStartIfOnBatteries'])
print(' StopIfGoingOnBatteries is ', ts['Task'][index]['Settings']['StopIfGoingOnBatteries'])
print(' MultipleInstancesPolicy is ', ts['Task'][index]['Settings']['MultipleInstancesPolicy'])
print(' StartWhenAvailable is ', ts['Task'][index]['Settings']['StartWhenAvailable'])
print(' RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable is ', ts['Task'][index]['Settings']['RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable'])
```

Comment: Have you used loops before?

Comment: regular loops ? sure.

Comment: Then just iterate the tasks?

Comment: That's the part i have problem with.When trying to iterate it doesn't work. Can't even count the number of tasks in the file.

Comment: I'd be happy to help but I'm still not sure what exactly you need printed. Those tasks shown in your code have all sorts of properties. How do you know which descriptions and properties to extract from each task?

Comment: Thank you. My goal is to extract the Author,URI and the command, but i guess if i can find a way to iterate and extract even one of them from every task i can do it for any other property by simply manipulating the string